# Change an existing js method without changing the original js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class that gets created (`testClass` for this purpose).  The class has the following method inside of it:

```
setExternalValue: function(val) {
        this.sliderCaption.innerHTML =  getPointsString(val*this.points_per_use, this.points_currency);
        this.sliderValuebox.value = this.getUses();
    }
```

How can I tie into this and listen for this method to happen?  When it's completed, I would like to run a specific function. Putting a custom event inside of the `setExternalValue` will not work for me because I cannot edit the original js.

Comment: can't you just alert(setExternalValue(value)) ? It doesn't seem like setExternalValue is doing any async process.

Comment: Once this method happens I need to perform an ajax call to update some data within the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap it, call the original function, then insert your handler code.

```
var myObj = new testClass();   // or however you normally initialize them

myObj.oldSetExternalValue = myObj.setExternalValue;

myObj.setExternalValue = function(val) {
   var result = this.oldSetExternalValue(val);

   // whatever you wanted to run after it completes

   return result;
}
```

```js
var testClass = function() {
  this.setExternalValue = function(val) {
    console.log("original setExternalVal " + val);
    return "return value";
  }
}

var myObj = new testClass();

myObj.oldSetExternalValue = myObj.setExternalValue;

myObj.setExternalValue = function(val) {
  var result = this.oldSetExternalValue(val);

  console.log("wrapper called with " + val + " after " + result);

  return result;
}

myObj.setExternalValue("foo");
```

Comment: Thank you.  I got this working.  I knew it was something along these lines.

Answer (score 1):

Make a reference to the old function.
Replace the old function with something that calls the old function but also performs new stuff when it finishes.

```
var obj = {   
    setExternalValue: function(val) {
        alert("inside method: " + val);
    }
};
var referenceOldFunction = obj.setExternalValue;

obj.setExternalValue = function (val) {

    referenceOldFunction.call(obj, val);

    // do stuff after it ends
}

obj.setExternalValue("test");
```

Comment: Paul Roubs is better than mine.